# Inserting data from Mariadb table into another table

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I couldn't seem to get the right syntax down in order to insert data from one table into another if `main_table` had an empty value for `email`. If the `main_table` email is empty for an `id` then I would lke to insert the `email` for that `id` from the `secondary_table`:

```
MariaDB> SELECT * FROM `main_table`;
+------+---------------------+----------------------------------+------+
| Id   | Email               | Other                            | More |
+------+---------------------+----------------------------------+------+
| 1    | user1@somewhere.com | blah                             | A    |
| 2    |                     | needs email from secondary_table | B    |
| 3    | user3@someplace.com | blah                             | C    |
+------+---------------------+----------------------------------+------+
3 rows in set (0.09 sec)

MariaDB> SELECT * FROM `secondary_table`;
+------+---------------------+-------+
| Id   | Email               | Info  |
+------+---------------------+-------+
| 1    | user1@somewhere.com | blah  |
| 1    |                     | blank |
| 2    | user2@something.com | blah  |
| 2    |                     | blank |
| 3    | user3@someplace.com | blah  |
| 3    |                     | blank |
+------+---------------------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.09 sec)
```

In this example `id` number `2` in the `main_table` has the `email` empty. I'm trying to get the `id` with the `email` from the `secondary_table`  inserted to the `main_table`. I've tried:

```
INSERT INTO `main_table`
(`Email`)
VALUES
( SELECT `Email` FROM `secondary_table` WHERE `Id` IN
( SELECT `Id` FROM `main_table` WHERE `Email` == '') ) ;
```

And various other failures along the way... maybe it's something simple, but I'm stuck!

Comment: `id` in `secondary_table` is not unique. You need to define which of multiple possible rows you want to use for an update.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel: I guess that's sort of another question apart from this. I have no idea where to even start on that one, considering that not all `Id`'s have a blank `Email` value underneath. Thanks for your all your great help, it was tremendous for the immediate issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking to your sample seem that you need  updated  (with join) and not insert
(assuming that the email field in main_table is null)

```
update main_table
inner join secondary_table ON main_table.id = secondary_table.id 
set main_table.Email = secondary_table.Email               
where  main_table.Email is null     
and  secondary_table.email <> ''
```

or assuming hat the email field in main_table is =''

```
update main_table
inner join secondary_table ON main_table.id = secondary_table.id 
set main_table.Email = secondary_table.Email               
where  main_table.Email = ''
and secondary_table.email <> ''
```

Comment: I get an error (for both examples) `Error : Not unique table/alias: 'main_table'`. I'm pretty sure `Email = ''`. I'm not sure what that error indicates. `Id` is `int(10)` and the rest are `varchar(255)`. If you need additional information just let me know - Thanks!

Comment: `ON` is missing

Comment: Since the `email` column in `secondary_table` can also be blank, you should add the condition `and secondary_table.email <> ''`

Comment: @PaulSpiegel: I had a question about that actually... sometimes the `blank` `Email` field contains another email address in the `secondary_table`, is there a way to specify to use last one that isn't blank? (eg. in `secondary_table` `Id` 2 could have `user2@something.com` and in the empty row below could be `user2.1@something.com`), so the `update` would use that one. It's not a huge deal if it's too difficult to do that, but I do have a few like that... thanks again :)

Comment: how do you assume that is the last .. without a proper order ..?

Comment: @scaisEdge: I'm assuming that the `Id`'s are in ascending order from what I can tell by looking at the table. There aren't many of them like that (which are not empty/blank underneath an email address), but it would be nice to know how to handle that I suppose - most of them follow the pattern in my question, so it's not a deal breaker.

Comment: then you have and id  ..  and an order by .. i suggestion you starting form this answer  to post a new one  with  a specific data sample  and the real result you  need ...because  your question about the last email  is really different respect  .. to the   this  question  i have answered  with  the update join ... eventually when you have posted  the new quesiton  .. comment me the related  link ..